# Revert an already pushed and merged commit in Git

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci

I made a few changes in my local and wanted to commit and create a pull request for it, but I also merged the master branch of the original repo(repo of the company I'm working with) into one of my remote branches and I need to reverse it.

[image: ss1]

So this image shows 2 commits, the first one, i.e, org-edit merge into org manage, is the part I want to keep and create a pull request for it.

The second one, which says merged master of ... is the one I want to reverse. This commit merged the master branch of the project repo I'm working on with a branch of the remote repo.

So I just want to keep the first commit and reverse the second commit and the changes it did and create a pull request for my first commit. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Does your existing Pull Request have only those 2 commits in it? And is `master` the branch you are merging into?

Answer (score 0):

Hit this command in your terminal with you commit ID

```
git revert <commit ID>
```

To Find your commit ID just Run in your termninal

```
git log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the revert command `git revert 4971fd0`

Then push your changes.

Where '4971fd0' is the id of the commit you want to revert from.

[Git Documentaiton](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given so far are wrong. You cannot revert a merge commit. Well, you can, but while this undoes the effect of the merge, the merge itself remains and will mess up your topology. You will have to *hard reset* back to before the merge, and then *force push* your branch.

```
git reset --hard @^1
git push --force
```

It would have been better to think before pushing in the first place. It's fine to rearrange your local topology, but it is not fine to rearrange history that has been publicly pushed. However, if this is a private branch (no PR has been created yet), then there's no problem.

Comment: The way I read the question, all of the answers are still wrong. :D My read is the commit OP wants to keep is at HEAD rather than the merge commit. (I think "first" and "second" are top down, rather than the order they occurred.)

Comment: I thought that too. In that case I'd just insert a cherry pick.